# Migration Issue with JBoss 6.3

Tags: java, migration, jboss6.x

I currently work on a web application project which plans to migrate from JBoss EAP 5.1 to JBoss EAP 6.3. As official migration guide pointed out, I place my war file in `${JBoss6.3_EAP_HOME}/standalone/deployments` and start AP Server via `${JBoss6.3_EAP_HOME}/bin/standalone.bat`.

When trying to deploy my war file, I encounter a Error message such as below:

```
JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newECDS': Post-processing of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.taiwanmobile.cse.business.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:165) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1442) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:587) [org.springframework.beans-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) [org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472) [org.springframework.context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383) [org.springframework.web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) [org.springframework.web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [org.springframework.web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.taiwanmobile.cse.business.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

My JBoss Data Source configuration file is as follows:

```
<datasource  jndi-name="java:/TCC/CSEDS" pool-name="CSEDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://172.17.33.21:1435;DatabaseName=CSE_DEV;SelectMethod=cursor</connection-url>
                    <driver>sqljdbc4.jar</driver>
                    <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                    <user-name>apxxxxx</user-name>
                    <password>CseUserxxxxx</password>
                    </security>
         </datasource>
         <datasource  jndi-name="java:/TCC/NEWECDS" pool-name="NEWECDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://172.17.32.81:1738;DatabaseName=CCCECST2;SelectMethod=cursor</connection-url>
                    <driver>sqljdbc4.jar</driver>
                    <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                    <user-name>apedxxxx</user-name>
                    <password>Ecgxxxx</password>
                    </security>
         </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="sqljdbc4.jar" module="com.microsoft"/>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>

My spring configuration:

 <bean id="newECDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:/TCC/NEWECDS</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link[spring forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/106149-spring-jboss7-aop-problems-to-get-datasource)  it seems to address my problem...